# How can I transform a specific time, to a

Tags: r, time, dplyr, chron

I want to transform a string column, into a proper format.

Normally I would do something like:

```
print(df$Time) 
> "00:00:01"
as.POSIXct(df$Time,format="%H:%M:%S")
```

However, my data is strange. It looks like this:

```
print(df$Time)
850a"  "823a"  NA      "906a"  "321a"  "1154p"
```

My solution is not working. Since I firstly stripped the characters (in this case "a" and "p"). But after doing that, my times are missing an important part (if it is morning or afternoon).

**Therefore my question: how can I transform this data into a proper format?**

Expected output:

```
df$Time_Old
850a"  "823a"  NA      "906a"  "321a"  "1154p"

df$Time_New
08.50   08.23    NA    09.06   03.21   23.54
```

**Some example data:**

```
vector_string <- as.vector(tv_Adds[["Time"]])
vector_string = vector_string[1:20]
> vector_string 


[1] "850a"  "823a"  NA      "906a"  "321a"  "1154p" "608p"  "1012a" "354a"  "1121p" "414p"  "1241p" "721p"  "223p"  "316p" 
[16] "345p"  "1145a" "3p"    "937a"  "138p"

> dput(vector_string[1:20])
c("850a", "823a", NA, "906a", "321a", "1154p", "608p", "1012a", 
"354a", "1121p", "414p", "1241p", "721p", "223p", "316p", "345p", 
"1145a", "3p", "937a", "138p")
```

Comment: Could you please share a more reproducible example? Perhaps a sample of your data, current and expected output? Your question is a bit unclear, at least to me.

Comment: Oh, so a and p are `am` and `pm`?

Comment: Hi @Sotos, indeed, a and p ar am and pm (yeah.. it is really messy)

Comment: @NelsonGon sure, I have added a sample of my data. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please do `dput(vector_string[1:20])` and post for your **example data** so it's reproducible?

Comment: Sure @Sotos. Done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your shared example, it seems that you have 3 different cases we need to handle.

1. When you have `834a` which needs to become `8:34am`
2. When you have `1143p` which needs to become `11:43pm`
3. When you have `3a` which needs to become `3:00am`

Once those are handled, in this case with a simple `ifelse` statement counting number of characters and modifying accordingly, then we can convert to datetime object simly by calling `strptime` with the correct format, i.e.

```
v1[!is.na(v1)] <- paste0(v1[!is.na(v1)], 'm')
v2 <- ifelse(nchar(v1) == 5, gsub('(^[0-9]{1})(.*$)', '\\1:\\2', v1), 
           ifelse(nchar(v1) == 3, gsub('(^[0-9]{1})(.*$)', '\\1:00\\2', v1), 
                                                  gsub('(^[0-9]{2})(.*$)', '\\1:\\2', v1)))

v2
#[1] "8:50am"  "8:23am"  NA        "9:06am"  "3:21am"  "11:54pm" "6:08pm"  "10:12am" "3:54am"  "11:21pm" "4:14pm"  "12:41pm" "7:21pm"  "2:23pm"  "3:16pm"  "3:45pm"  "11:45am" "3:00pm"  "9:37am"  "1:38pm" 

strptime(v2, format = '%I:%M%p')
#[1] "2019-10-29 08:50:00 +03" "2019-10-29 08:23:00 +03" NA                        "2019-10-29 09:06:00 +03" "2019-10-29 03:21:00 +03" "2019-10-29 23:54:00 +03" "2019-10-29 18:08:00 +03" "2019-10-29 10:12:00 +03" "2019-10-29 03:54:00 +03" "2019-10-29 23:21:00 +03"
#[11] "2019-10-29 16:14:00 +03" "2019-10-29 12:41:00 +03" "2019-10-29 19:21:00 +03" "2019-10-29 14:23:00 +03" "2019-10-29 15:16:00 +03" "2019-10-29 15:45:00 +03" "2019-10-29 11:45:00 +03" "2019-10-29 15:00:00 +03" "2019-10-29 09:37:00 +03" "2019-10-29 13:38:00 +03"
```

---

**DATA USED**

```
dput(v1)
c("850am", "823am", NA, "906am", "321am", "1154pm", "608pm", 
"1012am", "354am", "1121pm", "414pm", "1241pm", "721pm", "223pm", 
"316pm", "345pm", "1145am", "3pm", "937am", "138pm")
```

Comment: Your solution works! However, if you use the data provided, you should add (in front of your solution): 

v1 <- tolower(v1)
v1 <- gsub("a","am", v1)
v1 <- gsub("p","pm",v1)

Comment: Oh, I forgot to add that step :P...added it now. You can use paste and avoid doing 2 `gsub`

Answer (score 2):

You have to separate the hours from the minutes since the input, as you give it, is ambiguous. Then add "m" at the end of non-NA entries. I think you need this:

```
tvec = c("850a",  "823a",  NA, "906a",  "321a",  "1154p")
notNA <- !is.na(tvec)

#separate hours from minutes with a dot and append m at the end:
tvec[notNA] <- paste0(strtrim(tvec[notNA], nchar(tvec[notNA]) - 3), ".", 
                      substr(tvec[notNA], nchar(tvec[notNA])-2, nchar(tvec[notNA]))
, "m")

as.POSIXct(tvec, format = "%I.%M%p")
[1] "2019-10-25 08:50:00 CEST" "2019-10-25 08:23:00 CEST"
[3] NA                         "2019-10-25 09:06:00 CEST"
[5] "2019-10-25 03:21:00 CEST" "2019-10-25 23:54:00 CEST"
```

`"%I.%M%p"` stands for

`hour(0-12), followed by .,followed by minutes(00-59), followed by "am"(or "pm")`

Comment: Thanks @Grada! I used your code, but received an error: Error in strtrim(tvec[notNA], nchar(tvec[notNA]) - 3) :   invalid 'width' argument

Comment: I have added the data example that I used to test it... Many thanks again!